# Should we enable gif embedding?

Tags: feature-request

To explain **motion related issues or adding screen recordings** to answers it would be powerful to enable gif embedding. While answering [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14592/footprint-or-breadcrumb-animation) I've noticed that this is currently not possible.

Is this possible?

---

Edit: As **Professor Sparkles mentioned** this is possible. You can:

1. *optional:* upload your movie e.g. to [gfycat](http://gfycat.com) to convert it to a gif
2. copy the **direct link**
   [image]
3. click on **insert image** and paste you link
   [image]

This will **automatically upload** your gif to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com/) and insert it into the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is a way to enable animated gifs for the StackExchange image hosts I would be all for it.
For now you can just upload your gif to imgur or a similar image host and embed the direct link here.

F.e:

[image]